# On the notion of a component in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

Wikipedia article on a [component (in thermodynamics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(thermodynamics)) first mentions that:

> In thermodynamics, a **component** is a chemically-independent constituent
>   of a system. The number of components represents the minimum number of
>   independent species necessary to define the composition of all phases
>   of the system.

A bit later it is said in the same article that:

> The number of components is equal to the number of distinct chemical
>   species (constituents), minus the number of chemical reactions between
>   them, minus the number of any constraints (like charge neutrality or
>   balance of molar quantities).

How does the second statement follows from the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a reaction comes with an equilibrium constant, i.e., mathematically speaking, some equation on constituents. Now we have N unknowns (constituents) and M equations (constraints and equilibrium constants). Supposedly N>M. This means we can't determine all unknowns. To do so, we must fix N-M free variables. These are our components.